# Default ContextMenu showing up along custom ContextMenu

Tags: android

I have created a custom `ContextMenu`. But when I call the menu, the menu displayed also has the default menu.
Is there anyway for the default `ContextMenu` not to appear as well?

Code requested:

```
@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenuInfo menuInfo)
{
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    menu.setHeaderTitle("Recipients");
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_contacts, menu);
}
```

Comment: Don't self-deprecate. Also can you please include some more information such as the actual code you are using to create the ContextMenu and display it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Context menu is created by overriding `onCreateContextMenu` method. If you just inflate a menu from resource there no default menu can appear.

```
@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenuInfo menuInfo)
{
   menu.setHeaderTitle("Context menu");
   MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
   inflater.inflate(R.menu.context_menu, menu);
}
```

Comment: I did it the way you answered. But still the same. I don't want to have my custom context menu added to the default context menu. Any more ideas?

Comment: Ah, you have a default _context_ menu somewhere? What class are you extending? Just guess, but try to add `menu.clear();` at first line of `onCreateContextMenu`.

Comment: IT WORKED! Thanks Andrey! To think that a simple line of code solved my problem! I thought I had to delete something in the manifest file to solve my problem. Thanks again Andrey!